# Replace cells in a dataframe with a range of values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe that has certain cells which have values like: <25-27>. Is there a simple way to convert these into something like:25|26|27 ?

**Source data frame:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

f = {'function':['2','<25-27>','200'],'CP':['<31-33>','210','4001']}
filter = pd.DataFrame(data=f)
filter
```

**Output Required**

```
output = {'function':['2','25|26|27','200'],'CP':['31|32|33','210','4001']}
op = pd.DataFrame(data=output)
op
```

thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
def convert_range(x):
    m = re.match("<([0-9]+)+\-([0-9]+)>", x)
    if m is None:
       return x
    s1, s2 = m.groups()
    return "|".join([str(s) for s in range(int(s1), int(s2)+1)])
op = filter.applymap(convert_range)
```